# How to export only animation without mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, export

The question in the title is one way I thought of solving my problem.
My team and I are working on a VR project showing how the human body is affected by being overweight.
I have made the model with shape keys on the body and every individual organ too, so it can be used in Unity with a slider, it looks perfect.
I'd also like to make a basic animation for the character, but since I'm using shape keys, I cannot export animations with it because then the shape keys would be involved in that and we could not control them separately from code in Unity.
How can I only export only the animation I made on the rig from Blender to Unity?

Comment: so you just want to export the rig animation, without shape-keys, is that right? your question is pretty confusing to me because you wrote that much about shape-keys (which are mesh depending).

Comment: Yes, I need the animation separately, because the rig animation contains the body's movement and the shape keys contain the growth of the organs and the body. The shape keys can be controlled from code in Unity, but the rig's animation should be playing at all times, which means I need to import it into Unity separately, but I dont know how to export it from Blender (only the animation, without the mesh, if possible, or of course I'd love to hear different options for this problem too)

Comment: I wonder if the answer is that I delete the mesh, export that to .fbx and import to Unity? I jus wonder how that can be used on the mesh, how will Unity connect the two, that's why I'm confused.